# Pass multiple parameters on Laravel 4 DB::transaction()?

Tags: php

I am trying this:

```
  $iddocente = '1';
  $idcurso = '2';
  DB::transaction(function() {
    DB::table('users')->insert(
      array('docente' => $iddocente, 'curso' => $idcurso)
    );
  });
```

But no work. Help me please.

Comment: "no work" is not much to go on. can you provide more details?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `use` keyword is what you want.

```
DB::transaction(function() use ($iddocente, $idcurso) {
```